# Docker for dev and production

Tags: docker

Let's say I have some projects using Go and some Javascript Applications.

In development, I need to run those using `go run` or `npm start`.

In production, I need to run a compile version from my app `go build` or `npm build`.

Right now, I don't see how to use Docker for that: Should I create two containers: one for development (using npm start or go run) and one for production (it will build the app and serve it) ? It seems I will loose the benefits of using Docker if I choose this path.

**EDIT1:** One solution could be to use different command in production or development. But If my project takes 10 minutes to build, it will mean that everytime I deploy a container it will restart it's build which is not an acceptable solution.

How do you deal with those cases ?

Comment: Just run the same container with a different command. Read the docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

Comment: I don't want to build my app every time the container starts. If the project takes 20 minutes to build it's not a good idea to run it everytime the container starts.

Comment: Use `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`

Comment: This sounds like there are some problems here regarding SDLC processes that need to be fixed before trying to use Docker to help when it may only compound the issues.

Comment: I guess, now you are including your apps into docker image. How about to map your build directory on your dev computer to the folder in docker image? Our Java app is very big too and to run docker image on dev stations we map "target/exploded-war" to Tomcat's "webapps" folder in docker container.